# Speech recognition

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I'm running simple python server on my home network that serves index.html with [anycontrol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anycontrol)
speech recognition.

I can successfully open the page. But the page won't ask for permission to use my microphone. In fact it removes the option to allow the microphone [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYdCc.png).

What I've tried:

- Reinstall Google Chrome
- Tried Google Canary
- Tried Firefox (but the script is supposed to mainly work on google chrome)

When I create the file on my desktop it runs just as intended. But from the python server it wont. Any suggestions ?

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<title> Default website. </title>
</Head>
<Body>
<p> Index.html file </p>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/anycontrol/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var ctrl = new anycontrol()

  ctrl.addCommand("previous page", function() {
    console.log('Go to previous page')
  });

  ctrl.addCommand("next page", function () {
    console.log('Go to next page')
  });

  ctrl.start();
</script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using the required http*s* protocol?

Comment: @dandavis ok this will be the solution. I didn't think I would have to worry about https if its on my home network. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: you didn't used to need http, they changed it a while back, so docs or tutorials might be out of date.

Comment: @dandavis I'm going to give it a shot and let you know if it was the solution :-)

Comment: @dandavis Ok so the solution was adding https certification. Thank you for your help!